# Why is ls command slow to interrupt on NFS directory with lots of files?

Tags: shell, ls, wildcards, nfs

I noticed in directories with lots of files on NFS if I do

```
ls *
```

then hit Ctrl-C it can take a while ( say 20 seconds ) before ls comes back.

Why?  Can ls command be fixed to be more responsive?

Comment: `ls *` is going to cause `ls` to look at every file to see whether it's a directory. That can take some time over NFS. If you just want to list the contents of the current directory, type `ls`. (No `*`).

Answer (score 7):

When you run `ls *`, the first thing that happens is that the shell obtains a listing of the current directory. If the directory is huge and the server is slow, this could take a while.

Once the shell has obtained the list of names of files in the current directory, it sorts that list (which is very quick compared to any network interaction), then calls `ls`. The `ls` command looks up each file in turn and retrieves its metadata ([`stat`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat) call) to check whether it is a directory; if a file is a directory, `ls` lists its contents rather than the directory itself.

When you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, this won't interrupt the current NFS operation. You can't interrupt a filesystem operation just anywhere, as this could leave the system in an inconsistent state. Even reading a file might update its access time. Most of the time, an elementary read or write operation on a file is instantaneous by human standards, but NFS is an exception, especially with large amounts of data over a slow network.

Thus pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> will only take effect:

- if the shell is currently generating the list of file names, when that list is fully retrieved;
- if `ls` has been started and is currently obtaining metadata about a file, when the server supplies the metadata;
- if `ls` has been started and is currently listing a directory, when the list is fully retrieved, or at least after a chunk of it.

It's not the fault of the `ls` command (which may not even have been started yet). It's not even the shell's fault: it's NFS's fault. NFS is pretty slow.

Answer (score 4):

Hypothesis: traversing a directory over NFS is speculatively loading more data than you would expect at once.  Way too much IO on the server side, causing a single NFS call to take >20s.  mount with `intr` option might allow Ctrl-C to interrupt the in-flight call.

Google found a list of NFS calls which includes READDIRPLUS.  Basically readdir + then stat for each file.  Also getacl.  In other words there's one NFS call that basically does `ls -l` (for a certain number of files).  Instead of sending individual stat requests for each file.

Googling for nfs readdirplus - this looks quite plausible.  First result is a (paywalled) bug report.

> RHEL6: NFSv3 READDIRPLUS drastically slows down globbing over a NFS directory leading to performance problems
>
> - RHEL 6.2 with a standard mount, a glob in a directory containing over 3000 directories takes 218 seconds (nearly four minutes).
> - A mount of the same directory using the nordirplus option to disable the use of readdirplus calls, a glob on the same directory takes only 1.7 seconds

so that seems an interesting line of investigation.

---

EDIT: note that your example `ls *` is also a use of globbing.  `ls .` would avoid the glob.  If that makes a difference to your specific question, it could be because the globbing takes place in the shell, instead of ls, which might affect how the Ctrl-C is processed.  I doubt it matters, but it just struck me as an interesting question.

Answer (score 0):

There can be several reasons for the `ls` command to be slow on NFS directory.

- The directory might not be automounted.
- The machines may not be in the same network.

However, this is a more general idea rather than specific to *NFS*. To list the files with out sorting, 
You can try `ls -U` which lists the files without sorting. From man page of `ls`,

> -U     do not sort; list entries in directory order.  In combination
>   with one_per_line format ‘-1’, it will show files immediately and
>                 it has no memory limitations.

There are several variations to avoid sorting. You can check the man page of your system and try any one of the below options.

```
ls -f
ls -U
ls --sort=none
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an alias to ls may also cause slowness, try \ls  even \ls -altr OR any other options of ls.

Comment: How is prepending `ls` with a backslash going to bypass the alias? Using `/bin/ls` would work, though.

Comment: @zagrimsan running `\command` ignores any aliases and launches the system command directly. That's correct enough, just very unlikely to be relevant.

Comment: Live and learn. Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: This fixed it. `ls` was aliased to `ls --color=auto`, and it hung for like 30 minutes until I cancelled it. After disabling the alias it executed in 5 seconds. Seems adding colors adds a lot of overhead.